# Regex issue to remove hex LF

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to replace two items from a string

XA0 and A0.  The string may start with XA0 and have n number of A0's after that as such:

03/21/16 13:19\X0A\03/21/16NO EOSINOPHILS SEEN\X0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A\

In the above I'd like to see the first \X0A\ replaced as well as all of the 0A's in the middle and the last '\'

Not sure if the last set of 0A's should be considered one thing since it in enclosed in a \X and closing \ but it all needs to be gone.

Since this is a linefeed symbol I'd like to replace them all with BR.

Comment: You can try `\\?X(?:0A)+\\(?=\n|$)`, then replace by `<br>`

Comment: `XA0` is not the same as `X0A`. Can you be more clear ?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. Should be X0A

Comment: That got rid of the ones at the end but not the one in the middle - 03/21/16 13:19\X0A\03/21/16

Comment: Try [``\\X(?:0A)+\\``](https://regex101.com/r/tW6bJ0/1) and replace with an empty string/newline/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use

```
\\X(?:0A)+\\
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW6bJ0/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\\` - a literal `\`
- `X` - a literal `X` letter
- `(?:0A)+` - 1 or more occurrences of `0A`
- `\\` - a literal `\`